# VBA Split an array based on criteria dynamically

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a requirement to split an existing String() Array into multiple String arrays dynamically. Currently my array looks like this

My data sample/array looks like this:

> ID|Price|Supplier
>  01| 05 | Lowtown
>  01| 05 | Midtown
>  01| 05
>   | Midtown
>  01| 05 | Lowtown
>  01| 05 | Hightown
>  01| 05 |
>   Lowtown
>  01| 05 | Hightown

I do not know how many Suppliers i will have because the numbers will keep increasing.
I need to parse this split up this current array based on the Supplier's name
Array(1) = entire row of Lowtown values
Array(2) = entire row of Midtownvalues
Array(3) = entire row of Hightown values

```
Sub splitVendor(ByRef Arr() As String)

' Split string and store into X variant
Dim X As Variant

For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)

    X = Split(Arr(i), " | ")

Next i



End Sub
```

My intention is to create a loop that loops through all the data within the Arr to group up similar values, then store it into other multiple arrays dynamically(unknown amount of vendors)

Any help would be much appreciated!
PS: I just started VBA for a week, let me know if I can provide more information !

Answer (score 0):

Just go Text to Columns > Delimited > Delimiter = '|' > Finish.  Then, if you want to organize everything into groups, use a Pivot Table.  You can of all of this, of course, but maybe it is better to KISS, at least for now, and when you master all the easy things, move on to the more complex stuff.

Comment: Currently I have a need to run a macro because this is just part of the whole process. Thank you for the advice though ! I tend to over-complicate things